# Saving meta data/information in Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Is it possible to save meta data/meta information in Keras model? My goal is to save input pre-processing parameters, train/test set used, class label maps etc. which I can use while loading model again.
 I went through Keras documentation and did not find anything. I found similar [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6404) on GitHub but it was closed two years back without any resolution.
Currently I am saving all these information in separate file, and using this file while loading the model.

 Although probably not relevant but I am using `tf.keras` functional model and saving my model as `h5` file using `model.save()`.

Comment: i don't think `keras` model save file is expected to save anything but model parameters(layer weights, layer activation functions, etc)

Comment: A save file like that normally only contains the model parameters (also mentioned by okawo). You could implement your own metadata logging with `logging` and save that to a log file instead.

Comment: That's what I am currently doing @Cobalt

Answer (score 8):

This is working for me:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.saving import hdf5_format
import h5py


# Save model
with h5py.File(model_path, mode='w') as f:
    hdf5_format.save_model_to_hdf5(my_keras_model, f)
    f.attrs['param1'] = param1
    f.attrs['param2'] = param2

# Load model
with h5py.File(model_path, mode='r') as f:
    param1 = f.attrs['param1']
    param2 = f.attrs['param2']
    my_keras_model = hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(f)
```

Comment: It works also for json dicts with int64 values!
`f.attrs['categorical_values'] = json.dumps(categorical_values, cls=NpEncoder)`

Comment: For tensorflow 2.13.0 I'm not importing tensorflow.python.keras.saving, but using `my_keras_model.save(f, save_format='h5')` and `tensorflow.keras.models.load_model(f)`

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest think you could implement in order to satisfy your needs(at least part of them) is to save a `MetaGraph`.

You can achieve that by using `tf.saved_model` method (at least in TensorFlow 2.0).

Your original model can also be trained in Keras, not necessarily in pure tensorflow in order to use `tf.saved_model`.

You can read more about `tf.saved_model` here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model

Comment: Is there option to save meta information in `tf.saved_model`? I went through documentation but could not find anywhere.

Comment: I think the saved_model format in essence, it contains other information apart from the weights.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but I would love more detail here! Do you add a signature that just returns a constant tensor with the info you want?

Answer (score 1):

This is vile, but it works for me.

I have a threshold parameter 'thr' that is used in the preprocessing. I build it into the input name...

```
input_img = layers.Input((None, None, 1), name="input-thr{0:f}".format(thr))
```

In another program, when I read the model and use it, I scan the input name for the value...

```
try:
    thr = float(re.match('input-thr(.*)', model.layers[0].name).group(1))
except:
    thr = args.thr # default value
```

Perhaps this is not as nasty as it seems, for the input name describes the pre-processing the model expects for that input.

It would be nicer if the Keras model had a public metadata dictionary where we could stash stuff like this.

Postscript: I have removed this from my code.

It is only a few lines to save all the training parameters to a separate file. Once you set this up, it is easy to saved all the arguments and not the ones for your immediate needs. If you are really paranoid about syncing this data to the trained model, save the model name and creation time too.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by putting the metadata into a dummy layer's config. I couldn't begin to tell you whether this is sane or not.

```py
from keras.layers import Identity as IdentityLayer
from keras.saving.object_registration import register_keras_serializable

@register_keras_serializable()
class Metadata(IdentityLayer):
    """A non-training layer allowing us to pass metadata from training to inference."""
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # From Layer.__init__
        allowed_kwargs = {
            "input_dim",
            "input_shape",
            "batch_input_shape",
            "batch_size",
            "weights",
            "activity_regularizer",
            "autocast",
            "implementation",
        }

        super_args = dict()
        for arg in allowed_kwargs:
            try:
                super_args[arg] = kwargs.pop(arg)
            except KeyError:
                pass

        super().__init__(trainable=False, **super_args)
        self.metadata = kwargs

    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(self.metadata.items()))
```

Adding the layer:

```py
Metadata(key=value)(inputs)
```

Extracting the metadata:

```py
    for layer in model.layers:
        if layer.name == "metadata":
            config = layer.get_config()
            meta = config.get("key", [])
```

You'll have to have `Metadata` imported on the extraction side even if it's not otherwise used in order for the deserialization to succeed.